# Undefined index error fom tcpdf - using Prestashop

Tags: php, tcpdf, prestashop-1.5

Trying to debug this for a friend - 
While opening invoices in the admin interface, he gets half the page contents, and sees this in apache error log -

`Undefined index: cols in /var/www/tools/tcpdf/tcpdf.php`

Been trying to google it, but couldnt get anything substantial..

Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Difficult to debug with such limited information.  Take a look into installing some debugger like [`xdebug`](http://xdebug.org/), that should guide you to solution quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're running in a debug mode .... Try to comment the following line

file: **config/defines.inc.php**

find this line

define('_PS_MODE_DEV_', true);

and change to **false**;

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop's **tcpdf.php** needs a perfect HTML syntax from your **invoice.tpl** (or attached files like header.tpl, invoice.tax-tab.tpl, footer.tpl…)

Check this points :

- All `<table>`, `<td>` and `<tr>` are closed
- All `<td>` are in `<tr>` and all `<tr>` in `<tables>`

Because of Smarty syntax, it's complicated to use HTML Tidy, that's why, to find where my problem come from, I commented my code part by part.

If your Prestashop is < 1.5.6.3, check out this [buffer fix](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-1.5/commit/433a446a35ae5ef74fbf92a500b3a7e072b8a443)